# How to get welcome link for Community User?

Tags: apex, community, user-management, reset-password

Using "System.resetPassword(userId, True)" we can issue the reset password email to a community user in salesforce via apex:
[image: Reset password via apex]

But we also want to send the reset password link via SMS. Is there a way for us to get the link only in the apex so I can include the link in the SMS?

EDIT:: Just to clarify, "We are using a custom solution for sending the SMS (NEXMO service). I just want to generate and include the reset password link in the SMS content".

Comment: Out of the box - no. See https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l5rUAAQ

Comment: Just to clarify, "We are using a custom solution for sending the SMS (NEXMO service). I just want to generate and include the reset password link in the SMS content".